# How to securely connect to remote SQL from console application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, security

I wrote a simple console application that connects to my remote SQL Server. This script is manually being run from my computer. I was wondering if the connection string (user + password) is sent securely over the network by default or I should configure something in order to achieve it.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            sqlCommand, new SqlConnection( @"Server=xxx;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;")))
        {

            cmd.Connection.Open();
             //To some work
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Kind regards

Comment: Have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How secure the user name and password in the connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327041/how-secure-the-user-name-and-password-in-the-connection-string)

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327041/how-secure-the-user-name-and-password-in-the-connection-string